# Retrieve value on button-click

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

This is my code and I want to get value of `myText`. I tried with `appendChild` but it  doesn't work. How can I get `myText` value when I click on button?

```html
<div class="tut">
  <input type="text" name="" id="myText" style="padding: 2px; font-size: 18px; outline: none;">
  <input type="submit" name="" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunc()" style="padding: 2px; font-size: 18px;">
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>Coffe</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc() {
      var = document.getElementById("myText").value;
      document.getElementById("myList").appendChild();
    }
  </script>
</div>`
```

Comment: At the beginning I would recommend you type your query at Google. Read documentation about Element, Node objects. Such question might be resolved with your involvement and help of Google.

Comment: @ User which cast "close" vote, how is the present Question "off-topic" for stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 1):

There should be an identifier following `var`, before `=` to identify the variable.

Create an `<li>` element using `document.createElement()`, set `.textContent` to variable identifier from previous line.

Pass created `li` element to `.appendChild()`.

```html
favorite
<div class="tut">
  <input type="text" name="" id="myText" style="padding: 2px; font-size: 18px; outline: none;">
  <input type="submit" name="" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunc()" style="padding: 2px; font-size: 18px;">
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>Coffe</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc() {
      var text = document.getElementById("myText").value;
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.textContent = text;
      document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(li);
    }
  </script>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

For a plain text node, you could create one with `document.createTextNode(text)` and use it directly. Nevertheless you need still a node for the list element, which you can then append to the unordered list node.

```js
function myFunc() {
    var text = document.getElementById("myText").value,
        li = document.createElement('li');
      
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<div class="tut">
  <input type="text" name="" id="myText" style="padding: 2px; font-size: 18px; outline: none;">
  <input type="submit" name="" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunc()" style="padding: 2px; font-size: 18px;">
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>Coffe</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just wondering if li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text)); is better than li.textContent = text; after creating li element? Wouldn't latter be more efficient?

Comment: i am using a more node centric view to the DOM, actually i have not tested, which works faster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the value of the input into a variable.

Then, you need to create a new List Item DOM node to which you set the value from the variable.

Finally, you need to add the newly created list item Node to your list Node.

```html
<div class="tut">
  <input type="text" name="" id="myText" style="padding: 2px; font-size: 18px; outline: none;">
  <input type="submit" name="" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunc()" style="padding: 2px; font-size: 18px;">
  <ul id="myList">
      <li>Coffe</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunc() {
        var value = document.getElementById("myText").value;
        var newItem = document.createElement('li');
        newItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
        
        var list = document.getElementById("myList");
        list.appendChild(newItem);
      }
  </script>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your function to this:

```
function myFunc() {
  var myText= document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML+="<li>"+myText+"</li>";
}
```